# Quick Fix Java based Fix client - Is socket initiator and acceptor both needed for sending messages and receiving response back

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am working on a solution to send FIX messages generated for trades done to a third party system using quick fix java library. Third party system will some times send back response for these messages or messages related to these after some time.

My understanding is that I just need to start the SocketInitiator to connect to the third party server and send the messages using send method in session. When server sends the message back, I will get the callback in the Application class toApp method.

Is my understanding correct or do I need to start the SocketAcceptor in another session to receieve the messages from third party server.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. The `SocketInitiator` should be enough.

You can take a look at the [Banzai example](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/tree/fbddaf35d09afe269870e1a207a7239e2758704a/quickfixj-examples/banzai) that comes with the QuickFIX/J library. You will see your understanding confirmed in [Banzai.java](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/fbddaf35d09afe269870e1a207a7239e2758704a/quickfixj-examples/banzai/src/main/java/quickfix/examples/banzai/Banzai.java).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

Lets have a look at the basic definition.

Initiator : The party which initiates the connection to the remote FIX server (always using an IP address and a port number).

Acceptor: The party which runs the FIX process and monitors a particular port for incoming FIX connections.

You need not to set up Socket Acceptor as initiator itself will receive message in callbacks.